# Como fazer uma comparação de hora no sql sever

Tags: sql-server

Tenho uma consulta sql :

```html
select 
 HORA_FECHAMENTO, --campo char no recebendo a hora no formato 18:00     
 CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),114) as HORA_ATUAL
 from TB_ESTRACAO where IDEXTRACAO = 4
```

Quero compara a hora do servidor, ela precisa ser sempre maior que a hora  HORA_FECHAMENTO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embora não tenha especificado a versão do servidor, vai uma solução a versão 2008 ou superior.

```
Declare @HORA_FECHAMENTO char (5)
Declare @HORA_ATUAL datetime
Set @HORA_FECHAMENTO='04:59'
Set @HORA_ATUAL = CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),8) as time)

select 
 CAST(@HORA_FECHAMENTO AS time) as HORA_FECHAMENTO, --campo char no recebendo a hora no formato 18:00     
 CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),GETDATE(),8) as time) as HORA_ATUAL

IF @HORA_ATUAL > @HORA_FECHAMENTO
BEGIN
    print 'Hora servidor maior'
END
```

> HORA_FECHAMENTO | HORA_ATUAL
>   --------------------------------| ----------------
>   04:59:00.0000000   | 04:59:11.0000000
>
> (1 row(s) affected)
>
> Hora servidor maior

Comment: Resposta certa, imensamente agradecido!